# How to store multiple values from select subquery

Tags: sql

Hi I am having problem in the following query:

```
Update tbl 
set somecol = somecol 
Where Key = (select key  
             from tbl
             group by key 
             having count(*) > 1)  
  and Time = (select max(time) from tbl)
```

Above query works fine when there is only one key. But if there are more than one keys than this query doesn't work. How do I store multiple values from select subquery?  Also time column can be multiple. I am new to sql. Please guide. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `IN` predicate:

```
Update tbl 
set somecol = somecol 
Where Key in (select key  
             from tbl
             group by key 
             having count(*) > 1)  
  and Time = (select max(time) from tbl)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
Update tbl 
set somecol = somecol 
Where Key in (select key  
             from tbl
             group by key 
             having count(*) > 1)  
  and Time in (select max(time) from tbl)
```

Depending on requirement you can also use derived tables.